# Test predictive power of classes in multiclass classification

Tags: predictive-modeling, multiclass-classification

How can we confidently identify if the data has lower predictive power. I saw that the classifiers are giving poor accuracy (< 50%) on test data and approx 97% on train data. Correlation of a class with itself is less than other classes. KS 2 tailed test shows similar kinds of values for classes with KS statistic O(0.3 or 0.4). What more I can do to verify if the data has good predictive power or not